# How to install the JSON extension for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, json

I want to install the JSON extension as is mentioned in prerequisites to use People Api by Google. You can refer to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php).
I've php7 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I don't see where it is stated to install JSON extension, I believe Ubuntu programs can read that file already

Comment: @George "PHP 5.4 or greater with the command-line interface (CLI) and JSON extension installed." Copy/pasted line from the link I just shared, right under Prerequisites Heading.

Comment: Than How to check If it's installed or not?

Comment: Verify JSON extention installed or not using this command : `apt-cache policy php5-json` for php5.x and for `apt-cache policy php-json` for php7

Comment: Ok I see it's for php not Ubuntu per say

Comment: @Ravi I've installed php7. The command you mentioned is returning "Unable to locate package php5-json"

Comment: Please check if its there with `php -m | grep -i json` or `sudo dpkg --list | grep php | grep -i json`

Comment: @naan Here update me comment, please check again

Comment: @naan please check with `sudo dpkg --list | grep php | grep -i json`

Comment: @George  your command worked. It is already installed. Thanks

Comment: @Ravi your command also worked. It is already installed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON support comes pre-compiled with current php versions you can check for installed `php extensions` with:

```
php -m
```

And to check which is installed for the current php versions use:

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep php | grep -i <extension_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON extension is bundled with PHP 5.2 and up.
See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php) for more information.